# ModelBuilder with iterate raster - Tools won't overwrite temporary rasters from the previous iteration due to schema lock

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, iteration, lock, schema

I have a model based on an iterate raster.  One of the steps is to create a 'temporary' Viewshed, which after the subsequent process is intended to be overwritten by the next iteration.

However when the next iteration occurs I get an error saying there is a lock on the raster and it can't be deleted, where I only have one session of Pro open, no maps open, and certainly no use (as I understand things) of the temp raster.  Why and where is this lock being created and how do I prevent this situation?

The tool actually worked earlier, and I had started including some inline variables to make this tool useable for other purposes when the lock started occurring.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have an environment hierarchy setting problem where one of your environments is set to not over-write data?  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/what-is-a-geoprocessing-environment.htm